# Полная запись краткого выражения

Tags: python, python-3.x, числа-фибоначчи

Есть задача: найти сумму четных чисел ряда Фибоначчи, которая не превышает 4 миллиона.

```
num1 = 1
num2 = 1
print(num1, end=' ')
print(num2, end=' ')

for i in range(1, 32):
    num1, num2 = num2, num1 + num2
    if num2 % 2 == 0:
        print(num2, end=' ')
```

меня интересует строчка num1, num2 = num2, num1 + num2. как я понимаю, это - краткая запись выражения, как, например, i += 1 это i = i + 1. Какая полная запись будет для этой строки? спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например с использованием дополнительной переменной

```
t=num1
num1=num2
num2=num1+t
```

Answer (score 1):

> Какая полная запись будет для этой строки?

```
num1, num2 = num2, num1 + num2
```

формально это

```
(new) num1, (new) num2 = (old) num2, (old) num1 + (old) num2
```

или

```
(new) num1 = (old) num2
(new) num2 = (old) num1 + (old) num2
```

Полная запись этой строки именно такая как есть - "развернуть" её, не привлекая дополнительных переменных, не представляется возможным в общем случае. Хотя почти любой частный - может быть преобразован на выполнение той же самой операции без использования дополнительных переменных - но каждый по-своему, иногда даже с использованием совсем иной логики. Например, та же (по результату) операция без использования дополнительных переменных может выглядеть так:

```
num2 = num2 + num1
num1 = num2 - num1
```

---

**PS.** `(old)` и `(new)` - это не какие-то операторы преобразования типа, а просто маркеры "старое значение, до операции" и соответственно "новое значение, после операции".

Comment: Что это за синтаксис?

Comment: @Эникейщик Добавил пояснение... не думал, что оно потребуется, честно говоря.

Comment: Вопрос был "какая полная запись", а не что она означает. То, что написано у вас, никакой полной записью не является, потому что это не код, а фантазия какая-то.

Comment: @Эникейщик Мне кажется, что мы имеем дело с вариантом, когда автор спросил не то, что хотел, и его интересовала суть происходящего, а не полный эквивалент в "привычных" операторах.

Comment: Этот вариант тоже возможен 

Comment: @Akina В целом, вы отлично справились с решением моего вопроса, за что вам огромное спасибо.